# bash move is failing

Tags: bash, shell

I am running below commands in a script

```
move_jobs() {
  cd $JOB_DIR
    for i in `cat $JOBS_FILE`
      do
        if [ `ls | grep -i ^${i}- | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
          cd $i
              if  [ ! -d jobs ]; then
                 mkdir jobs && cd .. && mv "${i}"-* "${i}"/jobs/
              else
                  cd .. && mv "${i}"-* "${i}"/jobs/
              fi
          error_handler $?
         fi
      done
}
```

but it failing as

```
mv: cannot stat `folder-*': No such file or directory
```

Not sure why move command is failing with regular expression

Comment: What is your use-case here? Explain the problem and not show us why your code didn't work!

Answer (score 4):

Your script is overly complicated and has several issues, one of which will be the problem, I guess it's the `ls | grep ...` part, but to find that out, you should include some debug logging.

- `for i in $(cat ...)` loops through words, not lines.
- [Do not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)
- And if you still do, do not ever grep for filenames but include it in your `ls` call: `ls "${i}"-* | wc -l`.
- You do not need to check if a folder exists when the only thing that is different then is that you create it. You can use `mkdir -p` instead.
- Jumping around folders in your script makes it almost unreadable, as you need to keep track of all `cd` commands when reading your script.

---

You could simply write the following, which I think will do what you want:

```
xargs -a "$JOBS_FILE" -I{} \
  sh -c "
    mkdir -p '$JOB_DIR/{}/jobs';
    mv '$JOB_DIR/{}-'* '$JOB_DIR/{}/jobs';
 "
```

or if you need more control:

```
while IFS= read -r jid; do
    if ls "$JOB_DIR/$jid-"* &>/dev/null; then
        TARGET_DIR="$JOB_DIR/$jid/jobs"
        mkdir -p "$TARGET_DIR"
        mv "$JOB_DIR/$jid-"* "$TARGET_DIR"
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "No files to move."
    fi
done < "$JOBS_FILE"
```